# using input box data from one sub procedure to another

Tags: excel, vba

Need a little bit of help with a problem and I hope this all makes sense.

I have a sub procedure that sorts a form and then has an input box display asking for the users name.

I have the following code that does this then adds it to a specific cell on the form :

```
Dim UserName as string

UserName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter your Name", Title:="Name Of User", Type:=2)

Range("A" & LastRow).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name      " & UserName
```

This works perfectly but I also have another workbook open with some other data that gets sorted from the sub procedure after this one, which also works fine but what I would like is for the UserName variable to be passed to this other sub procedure so I don't have to have the input box display a second time.

I have tried declaring the variable as public and placing it both inside the sub procedure and outside all sub procedures with no luck.
I have tried assigning the UserName variable inside the sub procedure to a public variable UserName2 outside all other sub procedures and then trying to use the UserName2 variable again with no luck.

So any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
   Gareth

Comment: Store your workbooks in a variable and then fully qualify the ranges and then directly write to them. For example `wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Name      " & UserName` and `wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Name      " & UserName` If the procedures are in the same workbook then you can declare the public variable in a module.

Comment: Also please avoid the use of `.Select`, `Activecell` etc... See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in a **Standard Module**:

```
Dim UserName As String

Sub MAIN()
    Call FirstSub
    Call SecondSub
End Sub

Sub FirstSub()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = 3
    UserName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter your Name", Title:="Name Of User", Type:=2)
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Name      " & UserName
End Sub

Sub SecondSub()
    MsgBox UserName
End Sub
```

then run MAIN